Interpolation with function of 3 variables in maple
The value depends on three variables. I have a data set of type [x,y,z,w]. Here x,y,z are the input variables and w is the output result. Can I use maple to find a function that approximates a given relationship?
I tried using Spline and Fit, but it results in "Error, (in CurveFitting:-Spline) data must be 2-dimensional".

You can use CurveFitting:-ArrayInterpolation. But we cannot state the exact calling sequence because you have not explicitly described how the x,y,z data is laid out.

Another possibility is Interpolation:-Interpolate. But again the calling sequence (and possible preparatory data manipulation) depends on how the data is laid out (though this choice could also work even if the independent data is not regularly spaced -- which ArrayInterpolation would need).
